# Creating a wordpress function with the category ID as a parameter but can't get the right data

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a function inside "functions.php" that everytime I call it I only have to tell which categories ID I want.

The final result should be something like this:
[Mockup - Posts inside a Caroussel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ko3r.png)

Without a function I can do this inside "front-page.php" file, but the code will become too messy and repetitive if I start to insert more categories.

Right now this is what I have (front-page.php):

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">

  <?php 
    $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'orderby' => 'date',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'category__in' => 1515
    );
                
            $firstCategory = get_posts( $args );
    $i = true;

    foreach (array_chunk($firstCategory, 3, true) as $firstCategory) : ?>

      <div class=" carousel-item <?php echo $i ? ' active' : '' ?>">

        <?php foreach( $firstCategory as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

          <div class="card col-4">
                            
                            <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) :  ?>
                  
              <div class="card-header">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">

                  <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array(
                    'alt' => trim(strip_tags( $post->post_title )),
                    'title' => trim(strip_tags( $post->post_title ))
                  )); ?>

                </a>
              </div>
                  
              <?php endif; ?>

                <div class="card-body">
                  <h3 class="card-title"> <?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
                  <p class="card-text"> <?php 
                    if(has_excerpt()) {
                      echo get_the_excerpt(); 
                    } else {
                      echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 15);
                    }
              ?> 
                    
                  </p>
                    <a href=" <?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="card-link">Ver mais</a>
                </div>
          </div>
            
            <?php
            
            $i = false; 
            
            endforeach; 

            ?> 
            
        </div> 
            
          <?php 
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            
          <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>

      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a></div>
```

Quickly explanation, this code gets posts from a category and insert 3 posts each time inside a caroussel.

When I do it inside "functions.php" I can't retrieve all the right data. Only links and Title are ok.

What I could do until now (functions.php):

```
function displayCatCaroussel($categoryId) {
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'category__in' => $categoryId
);  

$firstCategory = get_posts( $args );
$i = true;

echo '
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">';
    
    foreach (array_chunk($firstCategory, 3, true) as $firstCategory) :
                
                if($i) {
                    echo '<div class="carousel-item active">';
                } else {
                    echo 'div class="carousel-item">';
                }

        foreach( $firstCategory as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);

          echo '<div class="card col-4">';
                            
                            if( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
                  
              echo '<div class="card-header"> <a href="', the_permalink( $post->ID ), '">';

                the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array(
                    'alt' => trim(strip_tags( $post->ID )),
                  'title' => trim(strip_tags( $post->ID ))
                ));

                echo '</a>
              </div>';
                 
                            }

                echo '<div class="card-body">
                            <h3 class="card-title">'. $post->post_title . '</h3>
                            <p class="card-text">';
                                                    
                            if(has_excerpt( $post->post_excerpt )) {
                             the_excerpt();
                            } else {
                             echo wp_trim_words( $post->post_content, 15);
                            }
                    
                  echo '</p>
                            <a href="', the_permalink( $post->ID ),  '" class="card-link">Ver mais</a>
                            </div>
                    </div>';
            
            $i = false; 
            
            endforeach; 
            
        echo '</div>';
            
            wp_reset_postdata();
            
        endforeach;

echo '</div>

      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a></div>';}
```

(front-page.php):

```
<?php displayCatCaroussel(1515); ?>
```

So thumbnail and "the_excerpt()" aren't working.

What I need to do to get all data right? and is this the right way to do it?

This is the first time I make a question here so if you need more info let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I genuinely don't know if this makes a difference or not, but I've never seen it formatted the way you have it... ...can you try changing `$post -> ID` to `$post->ID`.  And instead of calling `$post -> post_excerpt` try `get_the_excerpt( $post->ID )` within your echo statements.   I think you may need to adjust them all to use that pattern.

Comment: @TonyDjukic 
Unfortunately there were no changes but I will change it to the one you advised to keep good practices. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, let’s make sure it’s getting the ID.  Can you add var_dump( $post->ID ); to your file under before the thumbnail or export and lets see what it returns.

Comment: @TonyDjukic it returns the right ID of each post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things we can fix/improve upon, but your most pressing issues are

- `has_excerpt` accepts a post or post ID, change `has_excerpt($post->post_excerpt)` to `has_excerpt($post)`
- `trim(strip_tags($post->ID))` just gives you the ID back, you want something else, post_title maybe `trim(strip_tags($post->post_title))`?

Also, don't use `setup_postdata($post)` in your loop and

- use `get_the_post_thumbnail($post, 'thumbnail', $args)` instead of `the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', $args)`
- and use `get_the_excerpt($post)` instead of `the_excerpt()`

NOTE: default attributes for `get_the_post_thumbnail` are:

```php
$default_attr = [
    'src'   => $src,
    'class' => "attachment-$size_class size-$size_class",
    'alt'   => trim( strip_tags( get_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ) ) ),
];
```

Is short, your primary issue is that you're mixing up the global $post and the locally scoped $post (and it's meta data). `the_post_thumbnail` and  `the_excerpt` checks the global $post, but `has_post_thumbnail` and `has_excerpt` is using the local $post. Plus `setup_postdata($post)` is going to cause some cascading issues as well. The best solution is to ignore the global $post altogether.

Comment: It works, thanks! 
I had to add "echo" before "get_the_excerpt" and "get_the_post_thumbnail", at first I didn't realize it was necessary. As I understand it from the documentation. they return strings instead of echo, right?